# Terraform replace function strange behaviour

Tags: string, amazon-web-services, terraform

The situation I have is as follows, in Terraform I need to read a file as a string and replace all new line characters that match \r or \n with the replacement string "\n".

I tried two following ways but both yield undesired results.

this the file I have app.conf

```
hearing {
    foundation {
        data-processor {
            processor {
                genericFilter=default
            }
            sets {
                keyFilters=[
                    {
                        className=AllowList
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Result:

```
"hearing {\n    foundation {\n        data-processor {\n            processor {\n                genericFilter=default\n            }\n            sets {\n                keyFilters=[\n                    {\n                        className=AllowList\n                    }\n                ]\n            }\n        }\n    }\n}"
```

**Try1 with Result:**

```
> replace(tostring(file("${path.module}/app.conf")), "/[\r\n]+/", "\n")

<<EOT
hearing {
    foundation {
        data-processor {
            processor {
                genericFilter=default
            }
            sets {
                keyFilters=[
                    {
                        className=AllowList
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
EOT
```

**Try2 with Result:**

```
> replace(tostring(file("${path.module}/app.conf")), "/[\r\n]+/", "\\n")

"hearing {\\n    foundation {\\n        data-processor {\\n            processor {\\n                genericFilter=default\\n            }\\n            sets {\\n                keyFilters=[\\n                    {\\n                        className=AllowList\\n                    }\\n                ]\\n            }\\n        }\\n    }\\n}"
```

Can someone please help understand this behaviour? and how to solve it please?

P.S: Terraform version being used is v1.6.4.

Comment: I think you may be confusing "desired _output_" with "desired _result_" here. The "expected result" you shared seems like it would describe the same string as "Try1 with Result" and so it seems like you've already solved your problem, just that Terraform isn't rendering the resulting string the way you expected. (It's assuming that it would be easier to review a multi-line string if presented over multiple lines using the "heredoc" syntax, but that's just a UI presentation decision.)

Comment: In addition to @MartinAtkins comments the return of the `file` function is already a `string` type, and therefore the `tostring` function is redundant, and can be removed.